# Improving performance of ORDER BY without indexes in SQLite

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, indexing, sql-order-by

I am using Sqlite database of 1Million records. I have a requirement of sorting with multiple columns. For that i created composite indices on databases which improved orderby performance but the performance is still bad when we reverse the sorting order than specified in indexes.
For e.g. i have created index 
Create Index StudentIDNAMEIndex 
(
 SID DESC,
 NAME DESC
);

The performance of ORDER BY query degrades drastically when i ORDER BY SID ASC, NAME DESC or any other combination. As it is not possible to add index for each combination, is there is another way of improving sorting without indexes or using indexes effectively?

Comment: If you have so many records, maybe you should look into a more heavyweight database, such as Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, or PostgreSQL?  SQLite was designed to be simple and clean, making bugs harder to introduce.  The other DBMSs I named were designed for low bug count **and** for great performance.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @AdamMihalcin, it's worth pointing out that you don't have to pay to get a more heavyweight database, many are free or offer a free version with reduced capabilities (such as SQL Server Express), these free versions will still be much faster than SQLite for this task

Answer (score 5):

Sorting a million things is sorting a million things.  If you don't have it already sorted in the order you want, it will take as long as it needs to sort the data.

That said if the database is read only, you can get dramatic improvements in sort performance with a lot of works as follows.  Take each text column, and create a table with just the values of that column (in sorted order), an ascending id, and an index on the id.  In the original table replace the text column with the id.  In the end you'll get a table with a million entries, each of which is just a list of numeric ids.

You should find this table much faster to sort (because integers compare faster than strings, and you have less data to throw around during the sort).  You can still join to all of the auxiliary tables for the original text data.  However if you should want to enter a new piece of text that is not in your auxiliary table, you will have a lot of work to do.  And restructuring an application to use this structure takes a lot of work.

That said I've used this design in the past, and the performance improvement on read-only operations was extremely significant.  However the work necessary to make it work was also significant.